# Easy user interface change depending on selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

So I have a dropdownlist with 2 items : `Path` and `Queue`

If the item selected is a `Path`, then the next thing displayed in the next div is a textBox (`txtLocation`), and if it is a Queue, then I have to show a DropDownList(`cmbLocation`) which items are part of a xml file.

```
    Type:
    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbPathType" runat="server" Width="150px" TextField="TypeName"
                                            ValueField="QueueMonitorConfigTypesID">
        <DisabledStyle BackColor="LightGray" ForeColor="Black" />
        <Items>
           <dx:ListEditItem Text="Path" Value="Path" />
           <dx:ListEditItem Text="Queue" Value="Queue" />
        </Items>
        <ValidationSettings ValidateOnLeave="false" RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
          <RequiredField IsRequired="True" />
        </ValidationSettings>
    </dx:ASPxComboBox>


    Location:
    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Width="150px">
      <DisabledStyle BackColor="LightGray" ForeColor="Black" />
      <ValidationSettings ValidateOnLeave="false" RequiredField-IsRequired="true">
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True"></RequiredField>
      </ValidationSettings>
    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbLocation" runat="server" Width="150px" DataSourceID="queuesXML">
    </dx:ASPxComboBox>

    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="queuesXML" runat="server" DataFile="~/Config/Config.xml" XPath="queue/name" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

I know I'm using dev express, but that should not matter for this

Answer (score 0):

you need to work on change event of combobox. And Use the selection values as condition.

Comment: sorry for late comment. Actually this type of code is new to me. I think that there should have a combobox changed event. In which you can code. And In that you can check conditions on the basis of selected value of dropdown.